# Nested $group with different $match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Can Mongo aggregate this data:

```
{price: 100, name: 'itemA', date: '2019-09-09 00:01:10.534Z'},
{price: 150, name: 'itemA', date: '2019-08-09 00:01:10.534Z'},
{price: 50, name: 'itemA', date: '2019-07-09 00:01:10.534Z'},
{price: 50, name: 'itemA', date: '2019-07-06 00:01:10.534Z'},
{price: 200, name: 'itemB', date: '2019-09-09 00:01:10.534Z'}
```

into the documents that look like the following:

```html
[
    {
        'name': 'itemA',
        'last_7_days': {
            //sale stats from the last 7 days
            'min': 100,
            'max': 100,
            'avg': 100,
            'volume': 1
        },
        'last_30_days': {
            //sale stats from the last 30 days
            'min': 100,
            'max': 150,
            'avg': 125,
            'volume': 2
        },
        'last_90_days': {
            //sale stats from the last 90 days
            'min': 50,
            'max': 150,
            'avg': 87.5,
            'volume': 4
        },
        'sales': [
            //show recent sales (limit 3)
            {
                'price': 100,
                'date': '2019-09-09 00:01:10.534Z'
            },
            {
                'price': 150,
                'date': '2019-08-09 00:01:10.534Z'
            },
            {
                'price': 50,
                'date': '2019-07-09 00:01:10.534Z'
            }
            
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'itemB',
        'last_7_days': {
            //sale stats from the last 7 days
            'min': 200,
            'max': 200,
            'avg': 200,
            'volume': 1
        },
        'last_30_days': {
            //sale stats from the last 30 days
            'min': null,
            'max': null,
            'avg': null,
            'volume': 0
        },
        'last_90_days': {
            //sale stats from the last 90 days
            'min': null,
            'max': null,
            'avg': null,
            'volume': 0
        },
        'sales': [
            //show recent sales (limit 3)
            {
                'price': 200,
                'date': '2019-09-09 00:01:10.534Z'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried it mostly with `$facet` but I was not able to merge the code so far. Is this output even possible with mongo and with just one query?

Any idea how to proceed to the output that I have mentioned? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without using `$facet`. The idea is to tag each document if it's present in the last 7 days, 30 days, and 90 days and then group them based on assigned tags.

**The following is an example:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "info":{
                $let:{
                    "vars":{
                        "time_difference":{
                            $subtract:[
                                new Date(),
                                {
                                    $toDate:"$date"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "in":{
                        "tags":[
                            {
                                $cond:[
                                    {
                                        $lte:["$$time_difference",604800000]
                                    },
                                    "last_7_days",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $cond:[
                                    {
                                        $lte:["$$time_difference",2592000000]
                                    },
                                    "last_30_days",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $cond:[
                                    {
                                        $lte:["$$time_difference",7776000000]
                                    },
                                    "last_90_days",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$info.tags"
    },
    {
        $match:{
            "info.tags":{
                $ne:""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "name":"$name",
                "tag":"$info.tags"
            },
            "name":{
                $first:"$name"
            },
            "tag":{
                $first:"$info.tags"
            },
            "max":{
                $max:"$price"
            },
            "min":{
                $min:"$price"
            },
            "avg":{
                $avg:"$price"
            },
            "volume":{
                $sum:1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$name",
            "name":{
                $first:"$name"
            },
            "info":{
                $push:{
                    "k":"$tag",
                    "v":{
                        "max" : "$max",
                        "min" : "$min",
                        "avg" : "$avg",
                        "volume" : "$volume"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "info":{
                $arrayToObject:"$info"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "info.name":"$name"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{
            "newRoot":"$info"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7715b7f04b490307453d02"),
    "price" : 100,
    "name" : "itemA",
    "date" : "2019-09-09T00:01:10.534Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7715b7f04b490307453d03"),
    "price" : 150,
    "name" : "itemA",
    "date" : "2019-08-09T00:01:10.534Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7715b7f04b490307453d04"),
    "price" : 50,
    "name" : "itemA",
    "date" : "2019-07-09T00:01:10.534Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7715b7f04b490307453d05"),
    "price" : 50,
    "name" : "itemA",
    "date" : "2019-07-06T00:01:10.534Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7715b7f04b490307453d06"),
    "price" : 200,
    "name" : "itemB",
    "date" : "2019-09-09T00:01:10.534Z"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "last_7_days" : {
        "max" : 100,
        "min" : 100,
        "avg" : 100,
        "volume" : 1
    },
    "last_30_days" : {
        "max" : 100,
        "min" : 100,
        "avg" : 100,
        "volume" : 1
    },
    "last_90_days" : {
        "max" : 150,
        "min" : 50,
        "avg" : 87.5,
        "volume" : 4
    },
    "name" : "itemA"
}
{
    "last_30_days" : {
        "max" : 200,
        "min" : 200,
        "avg" : 200,
        "volume" : 1
    },
    "last_90_days" : {
        "max" : 200,
        "min" : 200,
        "avg" : 200,
        "volume" : 1
    },
    "last_7_days" : {
        "max" : 200,
        "min" : 200,
        "avg" : 200,
        "volume" : 1
    },
    "name" : "itemB"
}
```

**Query analysis:**

- **Stage I:** Adding tags into each document. The tags can be 'last_7_days', 'last_30_days', and 'last_90_days'. These tags are assigned on the basis of difference between the current time and the time fetched from the `date` field. If the difference is less than 604800000 ms. (millisecond equivalent of 7 days) means the document lies in the last 7 days and so on.
- **Stage II:** Unwinding tags
- **Satge III:** Filtering out empty tags
- **Stage IV:** Grouping on the basis of `[name, tag]` and calculating the min, max, avg, and volume.
- **Stage V:** Grouping only on the basis of `name` and pushing all tags and related data into an array as key-value pairs
- **Stage VI:** Converting the array of key value pair into an object
- **Stage VII and VIII:** Necessary formatting